# Which one is the targeting pack?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to open, in VS 2019, a project from another developer. When opening, it shows:

[image]

The second option brought me to [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral) which does not list any targeting pack. **Q1**: Am I supposed to install the full SDK or is the runtime sufficient?

**Q2**: If I select the first option, will the project be modified? If yes, I don't want to do that because the project is shared on TFS and that will force everyone to change.

My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Release has a value of 528040 which indicates I have .NET 4.8. **Q3**: How do I find out the list of targeting packs I have installed?

Comment: Someone answered to go to Tools, Get Tools and Features, and the list of targeting packs is under Individual Components. That is the correct answer, but it has been removed before I could mark it. Thanks. The link provided by the VS dialog shown in my question is instead wrong.